# How to check the value of a variable in my case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angular framework and I need to see if the data variable is changed when I click the button.

For example

```
 <button ng-click='change()'>{{data}}</button>
```

I was hoping to see if data change or console log the data variable. 
Currently its not working and might have a bug.

Can I do something like following:

```
 <button ng-click='change()'>{{data; console.log(data)}}</button>
```

Thanks for the help.

**Edit:**

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
   <button ng-click='change()'>{{data}}</button>
</div>


var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.data='5';  //this shows correctly. 

    $scope.change=function(index){
        $scope.data = '10'; //doesn't change after I click.
 }
```

Comment: You must have something else going on.  This works fine as simple as shown:  http://plnkr.co/edit/nXunX7kXcI7fsdAjk5JJ?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{{ data }}` is a view binding expression.  It simply prints out the value of the expression based on objects/properties in its scope.

If you want to log something on change then you can accomplish that within your `change()` function as defined in your controller.

The value displayed in your HTML will be the up-to-date value of data in that controller's scope.

Comment: thanks, the weird thing is the value looks good in my change method but it just doesn't display in the html .. +1

Comment: If you are not seeing it update in the view then you are most likely confusing scopes somehow.  If you want to post more of your angular code it might be evident where that's occurring.